# Gmail (Google) contacts fetching issue

Tags: android, gmail, contacts

By going this coding http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html i am able to get Contacts of gmail users but some times it gives me error like this http://postimage.org/image/vd0wer2xt/ , site also provide a source you can check it.in advance thank you so much

Comment: ronakmehta, did you get the solution for this?